# How to break a loop on the second click of a button

Tags: java, android

I am using a flash light blinking. I want to stop the flash blinking on the second click of a button.

That is, how to break the loop when clicking the button second time?

```
String myString = "0101010101";
long blinkDelay = 500; //Delay in ms
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
  if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
    // params.setFlashMode(FLASH_MODE_ON);
    turnOn();
  }
  else {
    //params.setFlashMode(FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    turnOff();
  }
}
```

Comment: You're talking about clicks. Could you add all relevant code for it? The portion you added could be anywhere in the app. How do you call it?

Answer (score 0):

make an:

```
int count;
btn.onClickListener() {
    count++;
}

 for(int i = 0;....i++) {
     if(count==2) {
         break;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a boolean variable and double click checker variable;

```
Boolean flashLightOn = false;
int click = 0;
```

Write a function

```
private void toggleFlashLight(){
if(flashLightOn)
      turnOn();
else
      turnOff();
flashLightOn = !flashLightOn;
}
```

On Button click

```
 onClick(View v) {
 click++;
    if(click == 2)
    { turnOff();
    flashLightOn = false;
    click = 0;
    } else {
    flashLightEnabler();
 }
```

Modify function like

```
private void flashLightEnabler() {
  for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
      if(click == 2)
      break;
              toggleFlashLight();
              sleep(blinkDelay);
}
```